# MVC 4 UserProfile Foreign Key / does not allow nulls error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I use the Entity Framework in relation with the MVC 4 authentication method. I've created a custom  `UserProfile` to include some other Tables.

**UserProfile**

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CompanyId")]
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

**Company**

```
public class Company
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
}
```

Now `WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount("MyUser", "MyPassword");` throws me following exception:

`Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CompanyId', table 'aspnet.web-67.dbo.UserProfile'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.`

I can remove ForeignKey, but after this the lazy loading seems not work any more.

Comment: Payment is Company? I can't understand this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that *CompanyId* column of *UserProfile* table was created ***not allow nulls*** in DB. You can write it as

`public int? CompanyId { get; set; }`

or you must add *CompanyId* value befor create user

Comment: You could also write is as `int?`. `Nullable<>` looks a bit old fashioned.

Comment: Advised by who? It's personal preference and I was just pointing it out.